# Data preparation to convert two date field in one

Tags: python, tableau-desktop

I have two date columns having corresponding Dollars associated in two other column. I want to plot it in single chart, but for that data preparation in required in python.

Actual table

| StartDate | start$ | EndDate | End$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 June | 500 | 7 June | 300 |
| 7 June | 600 | 10 June | 550 |
| 8 june | 900 | 10 June | 600 |

Expected Table

| PythonDate | start$ | End$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 June | 500 | 0 |
| 6 june | 0 | 0 |
| 7 June | 600 | 300 |
| 8 June | 900 | 0 |
| 9 June | 0 | 0 |
| 10June | 0 | 1150 |

Any solution in Python?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you a basic logic, you figure out how to do it. It's not difficult to do it and it'll be a good learning too:

> You can read only the subset of columns you need from the input table
> as a single dataframe. Make such two dataframes with value as 0 for
> the column that you be missing and then append them together.

Comment: Thanks for the logic and your time
Actually I need this for my ongoing project and I'm newbie in Pandas/numpy. can you please suggest code for this. I will try and reverse engineer to learn the algo/logic.

Comment: Steps: 1.Load all your data into one dataframe 'df'. 2. now df1 = df[['start_date','start']]  df2 = df[['end_date','end']] 3. rename start_date and end_date to 'python_date' in df1 and df2 4. df1['end'] = 0, df2['start'] = 0 5. df1.merge(df2, on = ['python_date'])